# Do accessing the Results cache in Snowflake consumes Compute Credits?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If i have ran a large query in snowflake and executed the same query after 5 minutes with out any change to the table etc. It is my understanding that the results will be fetched from Results Cache. In this case will it consume Compute Credits?

Answer (score 3):

Not today, BUT, if you use an unusually high amount of result cache compared to your compute credits on your account, you will begin to be billed for your services layer consumption.  There was an announcement on this in November that is important to understand.  For those using the system in an expected fashion won't be affected by this, but it's important to review:

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/whats-new-with-the-snowflake-cloud-services-billing-model/

Answer (score 1):

A few comments and updates about the product:  (1) . Mike Walton's response below about the upcoming service layer billing is indeed important to be aware for operations like result caching that were previously credit-free (compute credit-free).   (2) To understand what conditions required in order for Snowflake to reuse the result cache, this documentation link gives comprehensive list:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization  (3) The mentioned doc link also included the detail on how long the result cache will be kept:  "Each time the persisted result for a query is reused, Snowflake resets the 24-hour retention period for the result, up to a maximum of 31 days from the date and time that the query was first executed. After 31 days, the result is purged and the next time the query is submitted, a new result is generated and persisted."

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake Support answered your question here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000082DhlPSAS/does-a-cached-result-on-a-suspended-warehouse-cost-compute-credits

Answer (score 0):

Compute credits don't get consumed when you use the results cache so long as the query is exactly the same and the underlying table data hasn't changed. The results cache is purged after 24hrs too.